# Converting a 2D list to a dict

Tags: python

I want to convert a 2D list in a dictionary where the first element is the key and the second is the value of that key.

For example:

```
list = [[1,a],[2,b],[3,c]]
```

Turning into this dict:

```
dict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
```

I could achieve that using zip to separate the 2D list in two 1D lists and zip them into a dict, but the order of keys were wrong and I think there is an easier way to do that.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy:

```
l = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
d = {i[0]:i[1] for i in l}
```

Output:

```
Out[171]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Edit:

Even easier :

```
d = dict(l)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo, damn, gotta love Python

Comment: from the [dict constructor docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict): *If a positional argument is given and it is [...] an iterable object, each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.*

Answer (score 1):

More easier way:

```
l = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c']]
d = dict(l)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
lst = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]

dct = {}

for x in lst:
    dct[x[0]] = x[1]

print(dct)

# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```